# ActiveMQ securing Queues

Tags: security, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I am looking for a mechanism to secure Queue access on ActiveMQ. We are using Spring JMS to send JMS messages to ActiveMQ queues. Now the queues are publicly available within the company and we don't want just anyone accessing these queues and Post and Receive messages from them. Instead we want to secure them by a Authentication mechanism - preferbaly a username/password mechanism. Any cue regarding the same will be very helpful.

ActiveMQ - 5.5.1
Spring 3.X

Comment: Did you have a look at the ActiveMQ documentation?
Did you try any of the mentioned mechanisms for authentication? http://activemq.apache.org/security.html

Comment: Authentication is at the broker level not queue. Activemq provides various options.

Comment: Check --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494795/activemq-authorization

Answer (score 2):

Authentication is at the broker level not queue. You authenticate against the broker just like you'd authenticate against a database server.

Just like with tables in a database, you then gave to assign *permissions* to users and groups per queue/topic (user FOO can receive messages on topic A, user BAR can post to topic A, etc).

Unfortunately, this isn't as straight forward as in other systems. Databases have support for this kind of task, AMQ just offers an API which plugins can use to configure security.

Here is a sample configuration: 
https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/master/activemq-unit-tests/src/test/resources/org/apache/activemq/security/jaas-broker.xml

The login.config for this:
https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/master/activemq-unit-tests/src/test/resources/login.config

Base unit test:
https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/master/activemq-unit-tests/src/test/java/org/apache/activemq/security/XBeanSecurityTest.java

That should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

if you haven't already, take a look here: [ActiveMQ authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494795/activemq-authorization/31344110#31344110)

As mentioned by Aaron Digulla, You can manage your authorization directly in the xml config, or you can do something at the java level with a little bit of tweaking. We decorated the existing authorization plugin a bit which allows us to dynamically load authorization and groups from a file -- important if you don't want any downtime.

We applied the same technique for the ActiveMQAuthenticationPlugin, allowing us to encrypt our user/password file.